# How to copy doctrine entity manager

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Is there a way to copy an entity manager?

My use case is bulk processing.
From doctrine's own documentation [[link](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html)]:

```
$batchSize = 20;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10000; ++$i) {
    $user = new CmsUser;
    $user->setStatus('user');
    $user->setUsername('user' . $i);
    $user->setName('Mr.Smith-' . $i);
    $em->persist($user);
    if (($i % $batchSize) === 0) {
        $em->flush();
        $em->clear(); // Detaches all objects from Doctrine!
    }
}
$em->flush(); // Persist objects that did not make up an entire batch
$em->clear();
```

The issue is that if I do `$em->clear()` the entity manager will get destroyed and become unusable. Here is an example:

```
public function runBatchProcessingAction(Request $request, User $loggedInUser)
{
    $this->em->persist(new LogEntity($user, 'started batch processing'));
    $this->em->flush();

    try {
        $this->doBatchProcessing();

        $this->em->persist(new LogEntity($user, 'finished batch processing')); // $user no longer exists
        $this->em->flush();
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $this->em->persist(new LogEntity($user, 'failed batch processing'));
        $this->em->flush();
    }
}

private function doBatchProcessing()
{
    // Same as above, copied from doctrine documentation

    $batchSize = 20;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 10000; ++$i) {
        $user = new CmsUser;
        $user->setStatus('user');
        $user->setUsername('user' . $i);
        $user->setName('Mr.Smith-' . $i);
        $em->persist($user);
        if (($i % $batchSize) === 0) {
            $em->flush();
            $em->clear(); // Detaches all objects from Doctrine!
        }
    }
    $em->flush(); // Persist objects that did not make up an entire batch
    $em->clear();
}
```

I was thinking if there is a way to copy the entity manager and use that copy to do the batch processing, so $em->clear() will not destroy the logged in user entity.

Comment: Do you have any error ? what is exactly the behavior you have now ? clear method detach objects from manager, since you are flushing before, it shouldn't be a problem